# converting pdf to txt

Tags: email, pdf, text, ocr

I am trying to convert pdf's to text of the [Flint water crisis emails from Gov. Snyder](http://www.michigan.gov/snyder/0,4668,7-277-57577_57657-376716--,00.html).  Basically they have 20k+ pages of emails printed from Outlook and then scanned in as .pdf's.  (Obnoxious, I know.)  I have tried various tools like Tesseract (both directly and after having converted the .pdf to .tif with ImageMagik) and I just get a bunch of gobbledeegook.

Does anyone have any other suggestions for how to deal with these files?  I am able to open them in Acrobat Reader and copy out all of the text, but the result is poorly and inconsistently formatted, making writing one script to clean it up very challenging.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the record, a freeware/open source tool would be preferred as I am doing this on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quality of OCR directly depends on image quality, document formatting and layout, and the quality and proper configuration of the OCR technology you are using.  As the complexity of the document increases, usually you will be steering away from free OCR to more powerful commercial solutions to achieve higher OCR results.  IF you require formatting preservation, that alone exists only in a few commercial OCR applications.  Any one of the major OCR providers is your answer.

Consider using OCR-IT web-based API ([www.ocr-it.com](http://www.ocr-it.com)) for this conversion.  /one of the highest quality OCR on the market.  I am one of original developers of that system, and our goal was to achieve top quality on the market.

Also, if this conversion is for a good cause and for people's benefit, by a non-profit organization, a non-commercial project, or just a goodwill personal project, my friends and I want to help.  We volunteer and offer large-volume conversion for free.  We contribute our skills and high-quality OCR software in return for a non-monetary compensation, such as a mention in your project, share about us to your circle, spreading the word about our goodwill, etc.